# Linq to sql stored proc not returning results

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a Linq to SQL DBML

Contained within the DBML is a stored proc

When the proc is executed via Microsoft SQL Server Managment tool it return 60 rows.

Bu the DBML doesnt think that it returns any results.

Has anyone had this issue before or know how to resolve it?

Sp

**EDIT** Code:

```
[Function(Name="dbo.WQNT_PeekViewNextZone")] 
public int WQNT_PeekViewNextZone([Parameter(Name="Slot", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> slot) 
{ 
  IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), slot); 
  return ((int)(result.ReturnValue)); 
}
```

this is the code that Linq is generating the stored proc inserts into a temp table then selects * from the table at the end of the proc

Comment: How are you accessing the procedure using your context instance, can we see some code?

Comment: " [Function(Name="dbo.WQNT_PeekViewNextZone")] 
public int WQNT_PeekViewNextZone([Parameter(Name="Slot", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> slot) { 
IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), slot); 
return ((int)(result.ReturnValue)); }" this is the code that Linq is generating the stored proc inserts into a temp table then selects * from the table at the end of the proc

Comment: Try adding a log to your DataContext : http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/08/17/DataContextLogLoggingLINQToSQLOutputConsoleDebuggerOuputWindow.aspx

Comment: +1 DaveShaw. That helped me realize my parameters were in the wrong order...d'oh

Answer (score 2):

When you add a stored proc to the design, if you don't drag it onto an entity, it creates it the default way, which is to return the integer result of the proc.  If you've done any select statements in that procedure, you need to drop the procedure on top of an entity in the designer, instead of into the method pane, this will allow the designer to generate the appropriate method that returns an IQueryable of your entity type, instead of int.

Comment: OK cool, ill create a table that looks like the temp table and then drop the sp onto it.

Comment: It now says the result definition does not match the table definition when i drop the proc on top of the table.. argh

Comment: Finally after about an hour of searching, this sole answer helped all my understanding on how SP's work with Linq to Sql :)

Comment: Dragging to the design area is fine if your procedure only returns the value you want it to. Try setting nocount ON in your sproc to avoid it returning the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Either the result of your stored procedure should exactly match an existing table of your LINQ model or you should add both the stored procedure and the resulting element type to your dbml file. Usually the designer generates this for you if you drop your stored procedure anywhere in the designer (not on a table).

You should take a look at the dbml file to see what is happening. As an example, here's a part of a dbml file in my current project:

```
<Function Name="uspGetDepartments">
  <ElementType Name="uspGetDepartmentsResult">
    <Column Name="ParentDepartmentId" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int"
            CanBeNull="true" />
    <Column Name="DepartmentId" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" CanBeNull="true" />
    <Column Name="DepartmentName" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(200)"
            CanBeNull="true" />
  </ElementType>
</Function>
```

This means I have a stored procedure named `uspGetDepartments` that returns objects of type `uspGetDepartmentsResult`. Taking a look at the corresponding `designer.cs` file, I see:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute()]
public ISingleResult<uspGetDepartmentsResult> uspGetDepartments()
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(
        this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));
    return ((ISingleResult<uspGetDepartmentsResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

and

```
public partial class uspGetDepartmentsResult
{
    private System.Nullable<int> _ParentDepartmentId;
    private System.Nullable<int> _DepartmentId;
    private string _DepartmentName;

    public uspGetDepartmentsResult() {}

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(
        Storage="_ParentDepartmentId", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> ParentDepartmentId
    {
        get { return this._ParentDepartmentId; }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ParentDepartmentId != value))
            {
                this._ParentDepartmentId = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(
        Storage="_DepartmentId", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> DepartmentId
    { ... }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(
        Storage="_DepartmentName", DbType="NVarChar(200)")]
    public string DepartmentName
    { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the simple approach in the end

Stripped the stored proc to just return the empty temp table

dropped it into linq and then add the code than ran before the select command

not the best way but its only a small project

Thanks
for your help guys